# ImportError: cannot import name 'celery' from partially initialized module 'workers' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, celery

I am integrating celery with a flask app that is already written. The app has the following structure:

```
flask
    core
        __init__.py
    venv
    celery_app.py
    workers.py
    wsgi.py
```

The venv is a virtual-env which can be activated as:

```bash
source venv/bin/activate
```

I installed celery with:

```bash
pip install celery
```

And this installed `celery==5.2.7` and this is visible with `pip freeze` as well.

Now, the flask repo does not have an `__init__.py` file.

The `flask/core/__init__.py` file creates the flask app and sqlalchemy:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

I then created the `flask/celery_app.py` file which has the following code:

```
from celery import Celery
from core import app


##########################################
# CELERY SETUP AND INSTANCE
##########################################

def make_celery():
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672/BACKEND",
        broker="amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672/BROKER"
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
```

The `flask/workers.py` file has the following code:

```
from celery_app import make_celery

celery = make_celery()
```

The `wsgi.py` file runs the flask app with:

```
from core import app
from workers import celery

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = app(celery=celery)
    app.run()
```

After running celery in the `flask` dir with an active env, I am getting the following error:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'celery' from partially initialized module 'workers'

I don't understand where the circular import is arising from.

Comment: You have clearly not shown us the entire contents of `flask/core/__init__.py`

Comment: Please read [mre]. Make sure (by trying it yourself before posting) that someone else can **copy and paste** the code in the question, **without adding or changing anything**, to see the **exact problem, directly**. Then make sure to show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message, by copying and pasting, starting from the line that says `Traceback (most recent call last):` until the end, and formatting it like code.